# Show my friends that also Checkin the same company

Tags: php, laravel

I want to show my friends who check-in the same company. Here is my code.

```
public function show(Company $company)
{
    $authUser = JWTAuth::parseToken()->toUser();
    $userFriendIds = $authUser->friendslist()->pluck('id')->toArray();
    $profile = $company->where('id', $company->id)
        ->with(['subcategory', 'activities' => function ($query) use ($authUser) {
            $query->with(['activityLiked', 'comments', 'joins' => function ($query) use ($authUser) {
                $query->where('user_id', $authUser->id);
            }]);
        }, 'comments', 'companyCheckins' => function ($query) use ($userFriendIds) {
                $query->whereIn('user_id', $userFriendIds);
        }, 'companyFollowers'])->first();

    return response()->json(['profile'=> $profile], 200);
}
```

Please help.

Comment: What is current output and what is your desired output?

Comment: my current output is it shows all users but i want show only my friends who checkin the same company

Comment: Did you check and print_r() $userFriendsIds array??